# How to add an element under each product name on category pages?

Tags: magento2, category, blocks, magento2.4.6

How to add a subtitle / simple HTML element under each product name on a category page list?

I've tried various solutions via adding referenceContainers to the `catalog_category_view.xml` in my module and trying to target the various elements however never seem to be able to get the correct location.

For example:

```
        <referenceBlock name="category.products.list">
            <block class="MyModule\Reviews\Block\Product\Subtitle" name="product.subtitle"
                template="MyModule::product/subtitle_element.phtml"
                after="product.name" />
        </referenceBlock>
```

I want to do this in a way that doesn't involve overwriting the entire default magento `list.phtml` file.

None of the various hooks that I have tried to achieve this. Developing with `magento 2.4.6`.

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**No**, We can't insert any element below the product name on the product list page by the `catalog_category_view.xml` file only use the before and after of `phtml` file. Have you looked at the `list.phtml` file here Magento is using `foreach` loop for each product. We can't add elements between `phtml` files by any XML file.

For that, you need to override the `list.phtml` file in your custom module then you can add elements under `foreach` loop of products.

Thanks

Comment: Thanks, I've had to resort to a solution which overwrites the current list.phtml, I assume this method will conflict with other plugins which also try to adjust the catalog list.